# Is it a non-standard std::pair implementation, a compiler bug, or a non-standard code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

The following code compiles on VS2005 and [gcc-4.3.4](http://ideone.com/dAyEE).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template<class C, class T, T C::*x>
struct X { };

typedef std::pair<int,int> Pr;
X<Pr, int, &Pr::first> var;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "hello\n";
}
```

But it fails to compile on VS2010 with the error message:

```
1>d:\a\testvs10\testvs10.cpp(13): error C2440: 'specialization' : cannot convert from 'int std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>::* ' to 'int std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::* '
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=int,
1>              _Ty2=int
1>          ]
1>          Standard conversion from pointer-to-member of base to pointer-to-member of derived is not applied for template arguments
```

I understand that in microsoft's implementation of VS2010 `Pr::first` is actually a member of `_Pair_base`. However, AFAIK, it doesn't matter. `&Pr::first` still must be of a type `int Pr::*`. Note that the following code compiles fine:

```
int Pr::* x = &Pr::first;
```

So, is it a non-standard std::pair implementation, a compiler bug, or a non-standard code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard provides a clear definition of what a pair is, both in C++03 and C++11 the pair contains two member attributes, and provides exact code of what pair looks like. I would consider that behavior (moving the members to a base class) as a breach of contract as your code is valid according to the standard and it is being rejected by the implementation.

So the implementation of VC2010 is not standard conforming on this particular case.

Comment: "So the implementation of VC2010 is not standard conforming." -- news where? ;)

Comment: @Xeo: news nowhere with that sentence... I specified a little more, so that it might be news to someone :)

Answer (score 4):

The standard doesn't allow any conversion while matching the template parameters (looking for the standard paragraph, will edit in).

```
typedef std::pair<int,int> Pr;
X<Pr, int, &Pr::first> var;
```

This instatiates `X` as (`std::` omitted for brevity)

```
X<pair<int,int>, int, int pair<int,int>::*>
```

But the static type of `&Pr::first` is

```
int _Pair_base<int,int>::*
```

So the compiler would need to do a conversion like displayed in the error. I don't know exactly how gcc implements `std::pair`, but it seems to do so without inheritance. I'll look it up and edit again.

Comment: Why the type of `&Pr::first` is `int _Pair_base<int,int>::*` and not `int pair<int,int>::*`? I thought that the type depends on the way you access the member is the first place.

Comment: If it was `int _Pair_base<int,int>::*` then `int Pr::* x = &Pr::first;` would fail too, because you can't implicitly cast base member to derived.

Comment: @ybungalobill §4.11: "An rvalue of type 'pointer to member of B of type cv
T,' where B is a class type, can be converted to an rvalue of
type 'pointer to member of D of type cv T,' where D is a derived
class (clause 10) of B"

Comment: @ybungalobill: Also, try `int Pr::* x = &_Pair_base<int,int>::first` :)

Comment: OK, seems you're right about the conversion. But you still don't answer about the standard-compliance of the std::pair implementation and my code.

Comment: @ybung: Well, @David does, and I don't want to steal his answer. :)

Comment: @Xeo: *my* answer is not mine, it is just a bit of knowledge that is shared by many. I have actually voted your question, as I think that it provides valuable information (even if it does not answer the exact question of compliance).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a bug. Found the bug report here:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/558993/std-pair-members-are-not-members-of-std-pair